# Filter array with AngularJS in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I've got an array. If someone reserve a table, reserve in the array is set to true.

```
$rootScope.tafels = [
    {id: 0, text:'table 2a, 4 persons.', reserve:false}, 
    {id: 1, text:'table 3b, 8 persons.', reserve:false}
];
```

And I've got an function for returning the length of the array:

```
$rootScope.getTotaalTafels = function()
    { return $rootScope.tafels.length; };
```

Now the difficult part that I can not solve, maybe you can:

I want to return the total tables that are not reserved, with my function showed above. How do I apply a filter to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript 1.6 implements the filter function which allows exactly this:

```
$rootScope.getTotaalTafels = function(){
    return $rootScope.tafels.filter(function(value,index){
        return !value.reserve;
    }).length;
};
```

If you need to support older browsers there is a backward compatible function implementing this behaviour available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 2):

Use `$filter` with the last version of AngularJS ;)

Comment: Can you provide an example of how $filter would be used for the dataset in question?