# Angularjs ngrepeat incrementing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do i increment camp by say 3 instead of 1 , each time over here?

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="camp in camps">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
            <img src={{camp.img}} alt="" height="200pt" width="250pt"/></div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1">{{camp.email}}<br/>
            <span>{{camp.campname}}</span><br/>
            {{camp.about}}<br/>
            {{camp.tgtamt}}<br/>
            {{camp.enddate}}<br/><br/>
            <button id="view" class="btn btn-default" value1='{{camp.campname}}' value2='{{camp.email}}'>View</button>
            </div></div>
            <hr/>
        </div>
```

Comment: post your `camps` model in controller

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815320/filter-array-with-angularjs-in-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `$index` with `ng-show`.  Something like:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller = "myCtrl1"> 
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="camp in camps">
 <div ng-show="$index % 3 == 0"> <pre>{{camp.name}}</pre></div>          

    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl1', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.camps=
    [{name:"name_1"},{name:"name_2"},{name:"name_3"},{name:"name_4"},{name:"name_5"},
     {name:"name_6"},{name:"name_7"},{name:"name_8"},{name:"name_9"},{name:"name_10"}];    

}]);
```

Output:

```
name_1
name_4
name_7
name_10
```

see <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcUm6/3/)</kbd>